# Android charset problem downloading utf-8 webpage

Tags: android, utf-8, character-encoding, download

I have a problem downloading and parsing a UTF-8 webpage... I use the next function to get the web's HTML:

```
static String getString(String url, ProgressDialog loading) {
    String s = "", html = "";
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
        conn.connect();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        loading.setTitle("Descargando...");
        loading.setMax( 32000 );
        while ((s = dis.readLine()) != null) {
            html += s;
            loading.setProgress(html.length());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("CC", "Error al descargar: " + e.getMessage());

    } finally {
        if (conn != null)
            conn.disconnect();
    }
    return html;
}
```

And the web page has:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

But the Spanish's elements like: ¡ ¿ á é í ó ú  apears wrong in the app. I tried to use readUTF() but I have length problems...

Some ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `Reader` where you specify the charset used to read the input stream. In this particular case you need an [`InputStreamReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html).

```
Reader reader = null;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

try {
    // ...
    reader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
    char[] buffer = new char[8192];

    for (int length = 0; (length = reader.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
        builder.append(buffer, 0, length);
        loading.setProgress(length);
    }
} finally {
    if (reader != null) try { reader.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
}

String html = builder.toString();
// ...
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, did you consider using a HTML parser like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org)? It'll take this nasty details into account. It's then as simple as

```
String html = Jsoup.connect(url).get().html();
// ...
```

It however doesn't really allow for attaching a progress monitor.

Comment: Jsoup sure is faster and light... but what is better? speed and light or display to the user the loading progress?? Hard decision :)

Comment: If you intend to *extract* data from the HTML, I'd definitely go for Jsoup. It makes extracting very easy with jQuery-like CSS selector support: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: Really nice... I will try to use Jsoup!! Thanks again :)

Comment: Jsoup downloading is faster... but I have similar problem... I get &acute; instead á...

Comment: That's required by the HTML spec. You need to use `Element#text()` if you want to get the textual representation of the data. However `Element#html()` should work perfectly fine whenever you're going to redisplay it in a HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you don't want to use a DataInputStream.

This answer might be helpful though: [Read/convert an InputStream to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/in-java-how-do-a-read-convert-an-inputstream-in-to-a-string)